# Using a forked swift package as a dependency for Vapor project

Tags: swift, git, vapor, swift-package-manager

I've forked a server-side swift package for Firebase realtime db connectivity: [ferno](https://github.com/vapor-community/ferno) and I'm trying to use it as a dependency in my `Package.swift` like so:

```
.package(url: "git@github.com:3sidedcube/ferno.git", .branch("jwt3")),
```

however when running `vapor xcode` I get an error like so:

```
Error: Could not generate Xcode project: Completed resolution in 8.33s
error: terminated(128): git -C /Users/simonmitchell/Coding/Device-Monitor/.build/checkouts/ferno.git--4002215034454709000 checkout -f 155fa23f2f2d985dbee20072e560b095f61d7b63 output:
```

I've checked the docs for swift packages and this should all be kosher, so why isn't it working? Is this a limitation of swift package manager? Or of Vapor?

Comment: As FYI, I did successfully use the forked `3sidedcube/ferno.git` `.branch("jwt3").` The successful steps were (1) `vapor new Hello` project, (2) edit _Package.swift_ to add `3sidedcube/ferno.git`, (3) `vapor xcode`, and finally (4) run in Xcode. _So, at least in my configuration, this is not a limitation of Swift Package Manager or Vapor._ It would be helpful if you posted the _Package.swift_ in question and the more complete set of log messages related to the error.

Comment: I think all I needed to do was delete the `.build` directory in my Vapor project @l--marcl! Happy for you to put that as your answer if you wish?

Comment: My answer has been updated based on your feedback. Plz review. Also, based on prior experience, it's important to be observant of when one is using `.package(url: "git@github.com…)` versus `.package(url: "https://github.com…)` with the Swift Package Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are times when the package build needs to be cleared or reset to get things back on track.  The build can be reset with one of the following:

*vapor*

```sh
vapor clean
vapor update
# Updating [Done]
# Changes to dependencies usually require Xcode to be regenerated.
# Would you like to regenerate your xcode project now?
y/n> y
# Generating Xcode Project [Done]
# Select the `Run` scheme to run.
# Open Xcode project?
y/n> y
# Opening Xcode project...
```

*swift package manager*

```sh
swift package reset # Reset the complete cache/build directory
swift package update
# Fetching https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git
# Fetching https://github.com/vapor/fluent-sqlite.git
# Fetching git@github.com-MY-SSH-HOST:3sidedcube/ferno.git
# ...

swift package generate-xcodeproj
# generated: ./Hello.xcodeproj
open Hello.xcodeproj/
```

*manual build removal*

```sh
rm -Rf .build
rm -Rf Hello.xcodeproj
```

---

Also, in my experience, Swift Package Manager `.package(url: "git@github.com…)` protocol expects an SSH key pair setup for use with a remote service *for both public and private repos.* However, the `.package(url: "https://github.com…)` protocol does not need this setup because `https` provides a secure transport layer.

***ssh key pair***

If not already done, [create and setup a public/private ssh key pair for GitHub. ⇗](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/)

***~/.ssh/config***

```ini
### GITHUB-MY-SSH-HOST
### ADD REPOSITORY: git@github.com-MY-SSH-HOST:_USER_NAME_/_REPOSITORY_NAME_.git
Host github.com-MY-SSH-HOST
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_privatelocal_rsa
  UseKeychain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
```

*Note: More recent macOS systems require `UseKeychain` & `AddKeysToAgent` to work with `Keychain.app`*

***Package.swift***

Expressly declare the defined `MY-SSH-HOST` in the package `git` command.

```swift
.package(url: "git@github.com:3sidedcube-MY-SSH-HOST/ferno.git", .branch("jwt3"))
],
targets: [
    .target(name: "App", dependencies: ["FluentSQLite", "Vapor", "Ferno"]),
// …
```

Comment: This would be how to setup SSH for a private repo right? That doesn't seem to be the problem I'm having. It seems like support for forked dependencies hasn't been added at all yet to the swift package manager!

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered this was simply me not knowing enough about the swift package manager. After deleting the `.build` directory and re-trying it all seems to be working properly.